# AWS s3 bucket multiple StringEquals conditions policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a s3 bucket, that I need bucket policy to allow from AWS organisation IDs. I also want to put another condition for `bucket-owner-full-control` canned ACL. How can I modify this existing bucket policy to add the `bucket-owner-full-control` canned ACL?. Bucket policy is not allowing to add another `StringEquals` condition block.

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowOrgToPutObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalOrgID": [
                        "o-xxxx1",
                        "o-xxxx2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Prefer [Object Ownership](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html) to the bucket-owner-full-control ACL.

Comment: This is totally make sense. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can only have a single `StringEquals` key in the policy, simply put all of the conditions under the same key:

```json
{

    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "aws:PrincipalOrgID": [
                "o-xxxx1",
                "o-xxxx2"
            ],
            "condition2": "myValue"
        }
    }
}
```